# Understanding nonclustered index on partitioned table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I created a table which I horizontally partitioned with partition schema `PS_INTERVENCION([partitionKey])`.

Then I added a nonclustered index to it:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_INTERVENCION] 
ON [MEMORIA].[INTERVENCION] ([ID_INTERVENCION] ASC,
                             [ID_PERSONA] ASC,
                             [FECHA_REPORTE] ASC,
                             [COD_TURNO] ASC,
                             [partitionKey] ASC)
   WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF)
```

This index is created on the same partition scheme:

```
ON PS_INTERVENCION([partitionKey])
```

When I then go to check the partitions on this table I found these objects:

[image]

using this query

```
select 
    schema_name(c.schema_id) [schema name],
    object_name(a.object_id),
    a.name [index name], a.type_desc [index type]
from 
    (sys.indexes a 
inner join 
    sys.tables c on a.object_id = c.object_id)
inner join 
    sys.data_spaces b on a.data_space_id = b.data_space_id
where 
    b.type = 'PS'
```

Also if I check the boundaries of the partition everything appears duplicated:

[image]

using this query:

```
SELECT 
    v1.boundary_value,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(103), SUBSTRING(v1.boundary_value, 6, LEN(v1.boundary_value))) AS Origin,
    rows
FROM 
    sys.tables AS tbl
JOIN 
    sys.indexes AS indx ON indx.object_id = tbl.object_id
JOIN 
    sys.partition_schemes ps ON indx.data_space_id = ps.data_space_id
JOIN 
    sys.partition_functions pf ON ps.Function_id = pf.Function_id 
JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON p.object_id = indx.object_id
                     AND p.index_id = indx.index_id
LEFT JOIN 
    sys.partition_range_values prt 
CROSS APPLY
    (VALUES (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(103), prt.value))) v1(boundary_value)
    ON prt.function_id = pf.function_id
    AND prt.boundary_id + CASE WHEN pf.boundary_value_on_right = 1 THEN 1 EKD 0 END = p.partition_number
```

My question is: how many times is my table partitioned? Is the nonclustered index created for each partition?

What is the meaning of this duplicity?

Answer (score 2):

You may have the joins messed up in that query.  Try this one:

```
SELECT 
  tbl.name table_name,
  indx.name index_name,
  prt.value boundary_value,
  p.partition_number,
  prt.boundary_id,
  prt.value boundary_value,
  p.rows
FROM 
  sys.tables AS tbl
  JOIN sys.indexes AS indx 
    ON indx.object_id = tbl.object_id
  JOIN sys.partition_schemes ps 
    ON indx.data_space_id = ps.data_space_id
  JOIN sys.partition_functions pf 
    ON ps.Function_id = pf.Function_id 
  JOIN sys.partitions p 
    on p.object_id = indx.object_id
    and p.index_id = indx.index_id
  LEFT JOIN sys.partition_range_values prt 
    on prt.function_id = pf.function_id
    and prt.boundary_id + case when pf.boundary_value_on_right = 1 then 1 else 0 end = p.partition_number
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The result is the same as with the previous queries. There appear these two entries with the indexes names NULL and IX_INTERVENCION.

Comment: Even that your query returned the same output that mine, can you please explain what you saw wrong in my original query?

Comment: I didn't.  Unexpected dups might be caused by a bad join, and I had that one that I'd tested before.